# phpunit and symfony2 : how to assert number of queries from client or response?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit

I am using symfony2 and phpunit for tests.

Is there something like :

```
$client->getResponse()->getNumberOfQueries()
```

If not something similar, what would be the way to retrieve the number of queries from a response?

I'd like to check rapidly where I did not optimize my queries.

EDIT: my variable `$profile` seems to be always null

```
/**
 * @dataProvider urlProvider
 * @param $url
 */
public function testPageIsSuccessful($url)
{
    $client = self::createClient(array(), array(
            'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'xx',
            'PHP_AUTH_PW'   => 'xx',
        ));
    $client->enableProfiler();
    $client->followRedirects();
    $client->request('GET', $url);

    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    if ($profile = $client->getProfile())
    {
        $this->assertLessThan(10, $profile->getCollector('db')->getQueryCount());
    }
}
```

In lmy config_dev.yml:

```
web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false
```

still getting :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getCollector() on a non-object in D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\xxx\src\AppBundle\Tests\Controller\ApplicationAvailabilityFunctionalTest.php on line 59

Comment: See my answer again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In functional tests you can access the profiler, and get number of queries made during the request:

```php
class HelloControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testIndex()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $client->enableProfiler();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/hello/Fabien');

        $this->assertLessThan(30, $profile->getCollector('db')->getQueryCount());
    }
}
```

Make sure the profiler is configured to collect profiling data in your test environment:

```
# app/config/config_test.yml

# ...
framework:
    profiler:
        enabled: true
        collect: true
```

Learn more from the "[How to Use the Profiler in a Functional Test](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/profiling.html)" cookbook.

Comment: hi ! thanks, seems to be the right way, however retrieving the profiler the way it's described, I just get an empty profile, do you have an idea why ? (please see my edit).